# Set UTF-8 in (R package) cpp11

Tags: r, r-lib-cpp11

Update: From @tospig reply, I'm expecting there to be a `.set_encoding()` method on `cpp11::writables::strings`, which is a missing feature at the moment. Therefore, now I ask for an equivalent method to set the encoding.

I'm trying to understand a bit of Rcpp vs cpp11 and I found a non-documented case when trying to set the encoding, which is compatible within the std library.

This works with Rcpp:

```
using namespace Rcpp;
...
Rcpp::Strings x_utf8 = x;
x_utf8.set_encoding(CE_UTF8);
```

This doesn't work with cpp11:

```
using namespace cpp11;
...
cpp11::writables::strings x_utf8 = x;
x_utf8.set_encoding(CE_UTF8);
```

The corresponding error is `error: ‘cpp11::writable::strings’ {aka ‘class cpp11::writable::r_vector<cpp11::r_string>’} has no member named ‘set_encoding’`

Comment: Can you clarify what your question is? Are you expecting there to be a `.set_encoding()` method on `cpp11::writables::strings`? If so perhaps this is best filed as an issue on their github project?

Comment: Something like that. I updated the question.

Comment: As there is no question or issue for Rcpp here I'll remove the tag, amd edit the Subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such method as cpp11 uses UTF8 everywhere. From the
[vignette](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/cpp11/vignettes/motivations.html#utf-8-everywhere):

> ... whenever text data is converted from R data structures to C++ data structures by cpp11 the data is translated into UTF-8. Conversely any text data coming from C++ code is assumed to be UTF-8 and marked as such for R.